# Saving date as a string in Laravel

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

How do I make a date that was initially in the format **18-10-2019** to be **181019**? If the user registers, then the user will get a token number in the form of the date registered plus 1.

Comment: Hello Ahmad, please use "Date.now()" because of your date logic not be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by using `date` function

```
$d1 = '18-10-2019';
$d2 = date('dmy', strtotime($d1));
echo $d2; // 181019
```

Comment: Pls accept this answer, If it helped you, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can format it as such;

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$formattedDate = $date->format('dmY');
```